# Matlab project to iphone app

Tags: ios, xcode, matlab, vector, matrix

I have a matlab project that uses matrix-vector multiplication and then plots the results. I want to put this into iOS app (iphone/ipad app) I want users to be able to input vectors and matrices and then the app will be able to  plot the results. I am aware of matlab C coder but is there any better way of solving this? Thanks

Jason

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have been using appfurnace and is not working well. I noticed Mathstudio app has what I need but that has many functions and calculations.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB Coder would only help you for a small portion of your app, as it will only convert a subset of the MATLAB language into C. That subset includes things such as multiplication of vectors and matrices, but it doesn't include plotting.

If you have a need to do this in MATLAB, the best route to achieve it would be to use one of the MATLAB Builder products (such as MATLAB Builder for .NET or MATLAB Builder for Java) to deploy your MATLAB code (which can include plotting this time) into a component that can be called via a web interface. Then create your iOS app to allow the user to provide appropriate input, pass it to your deployed component over the web, receive the returned plots, and display them.